# From $\sqrt[3k]{\frac{2^k}{k}}$ to $\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\sqrt[k]{k}}}$

Tags: calculus, roots

Sorry if this sounds stupid, but can someone give me the middle step as to
how $$\sqrt[3k]{\frac{2^k}{k}}$$
leads to $$\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\sqrt[k]{k}}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean this? $$\sqrt[3k]\frac{2^k}k$$

Comment: @player3236 Sorry, typo. Edited the post

Comment: Hint $\sqrt[3k]{\dfrac{2^k}k}=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[k]{\dfrac{2^k}k}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $$\sqrt[3k]{\frac{2^k}{k}} \; = \; \left(\frac{2^k}{k}\right)^{\frac{1}{3k}}$$
$$= \left(\frac{\left(2^k\right)^{\frac{1}{k}}}{k^{\frac{1}{k}}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \; = \; \left(\frac{2}{\sqrt[k]{k}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \; = \;\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\sqrt[k]{k}}}.$$

Comment: Ahh that makes a lot more sense to me. Thanks a lot!